# Show bottom cards CardStackView

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently implementing this library: https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView

What I want to archive is showing the bottom cards when a card is clicked, like the preview on the page.

This is the code. I don't understand why they don't appear.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/topbar"
        layout="@layout/topbar"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/no_history_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/Title"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_default_big_space"
        android:text="@string/no_history_message"/>

    <com.loopeer.cardstack.CardStackView
        android:id="@+id/history_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        app:stackNumBottomShow="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topbar"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_estimation"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**CODE**

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val window: Window = requireActivity().window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.background, null)

        topbar_name.text = getString(R.string.common_estimations)

        history_list.itemExpendListener = this
        history_list.setAdapter(historyAdapter)
        history_list.numBottomShow = 4

        estimationLoaded.clear()
        cartViewModel.getCompletedEstimation(with(requireActivity() as MainActivity){ currentProfile.id })
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        historyAdapter = HistoryAdapter(requireContext())
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code i see you have made the `android:layout_height=0`

```
 <com.loopeer.cardstack.CardStackView
    android:id="@+id/history_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    **android:layout_height="0dp"**
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    app:stackNumBottomShow="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topbar"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_estimation"/>
```

but according to your source https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView, i see this

```
<com.loopeer.cardstack.CardStackView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

i think that might be the problem, try checking that and see